# keep getting "the password confirmation does not match" in octobercms, user plugin

Tags: octobercms

I dont know why this is but i created the register form in partial

```
title = "Seller-registration"
url = "/seller-registration/:code?"
layout = "default"
is_hidden = 0

[account]
[session]
redirect = "/" 
paramCode = "code"
forceSecure = 0

==
<?php
use RainLab\User\Models\User;

public function onCheckEmail()
{
    return ['isTaken' => Auth::findUserByLogin(post('email')) ? 1 : 0,];
}

?>
==

{% if not user %}
  {% if canRegister %}

    <h6 align="center" style="color: grey">Sign Up</h6>

    {{ form_ajax('onRegister') }}


  ...

    <input 
    name="password"
    type="password" 
    id="inputPassword" 
   class="form-control" 
    placeholder="Password" 

    >

    <input 
    name="password_confirmation"
    type="password"
    id="password_confirmation" 
   class="form-control" 
    placeholder="Password Confirmation" 

    >

    <div align="center"> <button type="submit">Register</button></div>
    {{ form_close() }}

{% else %}
    <!-- Registration is disabled. -->
{% endif %}

{% endif %}
```

but i keep getting this message

> password confirmation does not match

even when i try it without `password_confirmation`  field. Tried editing `Account.php` but it still comes up, though the user is saved to the database and i can log in with the user's credentials

Comment: hmm can you share what you edited in `Account.php` may be you missed something.

Comment: I changed it back to what was since it did not work. Even when i remove the validation rules, it still shows up

Comment: yes because `Account.php` has added rules by it self so it will be there all the time no matter what you do. - you can edit file and remove rule or make custom registration component. making custom registration component will be good.